# How to find the minimum value of $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x},x \neq 0.$?

Tags: calculus

## Problem

Find the minimum value of $$f(x)=\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x},(x \neq 0).$$

## Note

Maybe, you would consider finding its derivative. But, in fact, there exist infinitely many extremum points over its domain. This way can't work. By graphing, we can obviously see that there exist a minimum value point locating over $(\pi,2\pi)$ and the symmetric interval $(-2\pi,-\pi).$

How to show this fact?[image]

Comment: Besides, we may prove that the functional curve is sandwiched between $y=\pm\dfrac{1}{x}.$ This will help?

Comment: I think a possible way to solve your problem is to show that $$g(x) = \max_{|t| \geq |x|}{|f(t)|}$$ is a decreasing function of $x$. It's more or less like an alternative formulation. I don't know if it helps or not yet. I thought it did, I'm still thinking about it.

Comment: What's the problem with taking the derivative? We know we want the solution inbetween $\pi$ and $2\pi$? Then we can dismiss the infinitely many extremum comment right? Just focus on the region we want the solution in?

Comment: @Mason  You're right that we know we want the solution in that interval, but we must prove that. In other words, we should prove that the oscillations of this function become smaller in far distances.

Comment: Oh. We want to prove it a global min? But that shouldn't be so hard. We can argue the case that each minimum is larger than the last based on the nature of this function. '

Comment: @Mason  Yes, it's easy to see that. It's just hard to write it down. I tried to write it down though.

Comment: "This way can't work": though it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We consider only $x\ge 0$. Note $f\left( \frac{3\pi}{2}\right) = -\frac{2}{3\pi}$ and

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x} \ge -\frac{1}{x} \ge -\frac{1}{3\pi}> -\frac{2}{3\pi}$$

when $x\ge 3\pi$. So the global minimum occurs in the interval $(\pi, 2\pi)$. Taking derivative:

$$ f'(x) = \frac{\cos x}{x} - \frac{\sin x}{x^2}$$

So the global minimum $x_m$ should satisfy

$$ x = \tan x, \ \ \ x\in (\pi, 2\pi).$$

It seems you have to find that numerically.

Comment: Shouldn't the second line read "global minimum occurs in...." $(0, 2\pi)$?

Comment: It's positive in $(0,\pi)$ so I ignored that @stressedout

Comment: Yup. Makes sense. +1 for the way you wrote it. The problem was very obvious from the beginning, I just couldn't think of a way to write it down rigorously and clearly, but you did it perfectly.

Comment: thanks! but how to deal with the new problem? see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from John Ma's answer, the *approximate* solutions are (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function))

$$x_n = q -\frac 1 q - \frac{2}{3q^3}  - \frac{13}{15q^5}  - \frac{146}{105q^7} +\cdots $$ where $q=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi$, odd $n$ corresponding to minimum values and even $n$ to maximum values of the function.

Comment: This looks like a beautiful answer, but can you please expand your answer and make it understandable for newbies like me? I'm particularly referring to the part about the minimum and the maximum values of the function. Also, how is that series for $x_n$ derived? I checked Wikipedia but it seems like it hasn't explained how it's derived.

Answer (score 1):

Proof of the fact that minimum is not attained anywhere outside the intervals $(\pi , 2\pi )$ and $(-2\pi, -\pi )$: we can concentrate on the positive side since the given function is even. Let $x >2\pi $. Then $|\frac {\sin x} x| <\frac 1 {2\pi }$ so $\frac {\sin x } x >-\frac 1 {2\pi }$. Now consider $\frac {\sin (\pi +\pi /4)} {\pi +\pi /4}=-\frac {\cos (\pi /4)} {\pi +\pi /4}=-\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \frac 1 {{\pi +\pi /4}}<-\frac 1 {2\pi }< \frac {\sin x } x$. Hence the function does not attain its minimum at any point of $(2\pi , \infty )$. Obviously, the minimum value is negative so minumum is not attained on $(0,\pi )$.

Answer (score 0):

When $\sin x/ x $ is an extremum, by differentiation we get a transcendental equation

$$ \tan x = x $$

The graphs of $\tan x, x $ intersect at infinitely many points, supplying maximum and minimum values of its roots in alternate order as shown:

[WAgraph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%5B%7Btan%20x,%20x,%20sin%20x%20%2Fx%20%7D,%20%7Bx,%20-5,5%7D%5D)

Only the first minima ( near$\approx 4.49341..$ ) are required. They can be found by e.g., Newton-Raphson iteration.